# Соединения с удаленной бд

Tags: postgresql, сервер, centos

Есть Server Centoc 7 туда поставил 'posthgresql' в настройках  postgresql.conf заменил на такой l

> isten_addresses = '*'

а в pg_hba.conf заменил на такое

```
host all all 0.0.0.0/0  md5  
host all all      ::/0  md5
```

при соединении с psql -h X.X.X.X -U postgres кидает exception

could not connect to server: Connection timed out
    Is the server running on host "X.X.X.X" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Comment: Файрвол проверяли?

Comment: и на всякий случай - базу рестартовали после смены listen_addresses? reload недостаточно, нужен именно рестарт.

Comment: да    рестартнул базу

Comment: тока 80 порт проверил

Comment: а зачем Вам порт 80, когда он пытается по порту 5432 приконнектиться?

Comment: когда томкат запускали проверяли 80 порт имею ввиду что там фажрвол не стоить

Comment: Ну, допустим... что покажет `ss -tunap | grep 5432` на сервере с postgres?

Comment: Локально на самом сервере попробовать войти: psql -h <ip внешний сервера> -U postgres

Comment: я извиняюсь что так долго ответил вам tcp    LISTEN     0      128       *:5432                  *:*                   users:(("postmaster",pid=10694,fd=3))
tcp    LISTEN     0      128      :::5432                 :::*                   users:(("postmaster",pid=10694,fd=4))
 вот что пишет

Comment: yum install iptables-services
установил       iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 5432 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
service iptables save  и рестартнул не помогло

Answer (score 1):

На CentOS 7 работает сервер баз данных postgresql. В pg_hba.conf доступ разрешен, но может selinux не пускает?

```
tail -f /var/log/audit/audit.log
```

Попробуйте выставить разрешения.

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db 1
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_db 1
```

(https://centos.name/?page/FAQ/centos7)

Comment: Boolean httpd_can_network_db is not defined
при вызове